# Overriding Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

In my custom module, I'm trying to override `Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList` class (more precisely: I want to override function `getFilters`).

In the module's `etc\di.xml` there are:

1. One plugin statement
2. One preference statement

The plugin is working perfect, while preference is completely ignored.

```
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList" type="\vendor\module\Model\Layer\FilterList"/>

<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
    <plugin name="logProductName" type="\vendor\module\Plugin\ProductName" />
</type>
```

I double checked all class references - all's good. Please let me know what I'm missing.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why you are overriding this method ? You can use simply plugin feature because this getFilters method is public

Comment: I know it's public. However, in my case is simplier to use overriding. Any ideas?

Comment: Just use around plugin and don't call original method($procede() closure) , and do your magic :)

Comment: Thanks Keyur. Just done it with plugin. I'm not calling the original method. I do my magic ;) - However, I have problem with accessing protected variables. How do I access them?

Comment: You can define protected variable in your file and Inject \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList into constructor so you can call createAttributeFilter () method

Comment: Got something like this:

protected $filter;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList $filter
    ) {
        $this->filter = $filter;
    }

and got this error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeListInterface

Comment: my function:  aroundGetFilters(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList $filter, callable $proceed, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer) { .. }

Answer (score 4):

Here is full code to Override **`Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList`** this class

I can use **virtualType** method for override instead of **preference**

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Pradip_LayerModel',
    __DIR__
);
```

etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Pradip_LayerModel" setup_version="0.1.0"/>        
</config>
```

etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <virtualType name="categoryFilterList" type="Pradip\LayerModel\Model\Layer\FilterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filterableAttributes" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>    
</config>
```

Model/Layer/FilterList.php

```
<?php

namespace Pradip\LayerModel\Model\Layer;

/**
 * Override FilterList Class
*/
class FilterList extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList
    {
        public function getFilters(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer)
        {
            //echo "you can write code changes here"; exit;
            if (!count($this->filters)) {
                $this->filters = [
                    $this->objectManager->create($this->filterTypes[self::CATEGORY_FILTER], ['layer' => $layer]),
                ];
                foreach ($this->filterableAttributes->getList() as $attribute) {
                    $this->filters[] = $this->createAttributeFilter($attribute, $layer);
                }
            }
            return $this->filters;
        }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: This is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

May be below code is work for you.

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Layer\FilterList"/>
 </config>
```

use this instead of

```
 <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList" type="\Vendor\Module\Model\Layer\FilterList"/>
```

and make sure you have to re-compile, or remove var/di, var/generation etc.

and you have to extends this `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList` core class in your custom class.